# I am trying to download video using pytube however for some reason no sound is downloaded

Tags: python, pytube

When running the following program a video is downloaded however it appears there is no sound. Can someone help me to fix it?

```
from pytube import YouTube

path = '/home/15g2leve'
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyQjVtIGQg8"
resol = "1080p"
file_type = "mp4"


video = YouTube(url)

Streams = video.streams

vid = Streams.filter(res = resol, file_extension = file_type).first()

vid.download(path)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"You may notice that some streams listed have both a video codec and audio codec, while others have just video or just audio, this is a result of YouTube supporting a streaming technique called Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP (DASH)."
[refs](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/blob/master/docs/user/quickstart.rst)

So, you can use `streams.filter(progressive=True).all()` to get videos which contains both video & audio (vcodec, acodec info) or you download video and audio. After that, use a tool such as FFmpeg to merge audio into video.

Answer (score -1):

Use pytube3 with the `get_highest_resolution` function

Comment: The user is having a problem with audio the snippet you are suggesting is for video.